# test if input has only Arabic characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if an input text has only Arabic text in it's value.

This is what I tried :

```
var test = function() {
    var isArabic = /^([\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufbc1]|[\ufbd3-\ufd3f]|[\ufd50-\ufd8f]|[\ufd92-\ufdc7]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]|[\ufdf0-\ufdfd]|[ ])*$/g;        
          if(isArabic.test($.trim($('#arabicFirstname').val()))){
            console.log('is arabic');
          }else{
            console.log('not arabic');
          }
}
```

But I'm always getting `not arabic` even though I only type Arabic characters.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the jQuery selector like `.arabicFirstname` or `#arabicFirstname` in the following:

**arabicFirstname is Class Name:**

```
if(isArabic.test($('.arabicFirstname').val())){
   console.log('is arabic');
}else{
   console.log('not arabic');
}
```

**arabicFirstname is ID:**

```
if(isArabic.test($('#arabicFirstname').val())){
   console.log('is arabic');
}else{
   console.log('not arabic');
}
```

Comment: How did I missed that xD, another issue is when I type a space between two words for example `محمد علي` that regex is not working

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU Try this and let me know. var isArabic = /^([\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufbc1]|[\ufbd3-\ufd3f]|[\ufd50-\ufd8f]|[\ufd92-\ufdc7]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]|[\ufdf0-\ufdfd]|[ ])*$/g;

Comment: that works but when I type only spaces it works also which I can notice from here : `|[ ]`

Comment: Try this $.trim($('.arabicFirstname').val())

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU Thanks :-)